# Basic Syntax for String Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am teaching myself python specifically to process a very large text document.

What the code should do is read in one line of the file, split it on the pipe delimiter, if the value of the 23rd column is not 0 then it changes the first value (in the below to "AAA"), reconnect the line with pipes, and then print it to a new file.

When I run this however it does not alter the first column like I would anticipate it just writes the original line into the new file. What part of my syntax/method is incorrect?

```
counter=1
for line in open(r"C:\path\small_file_1000000.txt"):
    spline = line.split("|")
    if counter==1:
        with open(r"C:\path\PythonWrittenData.txt",'a') as NewFile:
            NewFile.write(line)

    elif counter > 1 and not spline[23]=="0.00":
                spline[0]= 'AAA'
                s="|"
                newline=s.join(spline)

                with open(r"C:\path\PythonWrittenData.txt",'a') as NewFile:
                    NewFile.write(newline)

counter+=1          
if counter%100000==0: print("Status Update: \n", "{:,}".format(counter))
```

I have looked on Google and a lot of places say you can overwrite an item in a list just by saying `list[number] = "New Value"` , but that is not working and I don't know why.

Comment: According to your code you increase the counter _after_ the loop, not _in_ the loop. So `counter > 1` will never be `True`.

Comment: Is `counter+=1` inside loop?

Comment: You never increment the counter in the loop. You only increment it after the loop is done. At least, given the indentation in your post here.

Comment: BTW, I wouldn't reopen the file before each write. Wrap the whole loop in a `with open(...`.

Comment: @ All: Oooohhhh... I'm not used to a language where indentation actually matters for the code. That make a lot of sense. I tested that and now it works. Thank you very much!